# Why my 8081 port is listening to some or the other process continuously even after kill process?

Tags: process, react-native, port

I am new to Coding and Computer Science,  and i was working with React-native on Android Studio. Whenever i start to use the simulator on the machine it asks me this:

ERROR  Packager can't listen on port 8081
Most likely another process is already using this port
Run the following command to find out which process:

Tough i have killed the process listening to Port 8081 the previous time i have started the simulator but it asks me agaain. Wants to understand what port 8081 is assigned to once it is killed using the taskkill /f /pid $$$$

Answer (score 0):

Hey even i had the same issue,i solved it by the following:

```
1.) lsof -i :8081 
2.) kill -9 <PID>   kill the process that is running on the port 8081 by specifing the PID that you get as a result of step 1.
OR
You can try running it on another port by using the command 'react-native start --port=8088'
```

If you get an error stating "Could not connect to development server" then try npm start,it should work.